# How to fix pip on an existing Pycharm project

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm trying to update pip in an existing Pycharm project, as it's on version 10.0.1 according to the terminal in Pycharm and I need the latest.

Pip is to the latest version of Project Interpreter and I've updated it on the Windows Command Line.

I'm expecting the results to be pip 19.1.1, but it's 10.0.1

Comment: you may have two Pythons installed and every Python may have own `pip` to install own modules. You can also use `python -m pip install -U pip` to run `pip` with selected Python.

Comment: So when I run that command in my PyCharm terminal, I get the following results: 
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\users\UserID\pycharmprojects\test\venv\lib\site-packages (19.1.1)

However, when I type in pip -- version, I get this: 
pip 10.0.1 from c:\users\UserID\pycharmprojects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-10.0.1-py3.7.egg\pip (python 3.7)

Comment: In your pycharm terminal, where you typed the above command and got the requirement up to date message, what does it say when you type python --version?

Comment: check `python -m pip  --version`. It looks like you have two Pythons and you use `pip` for different version. I see you use `venv` so it should create `pip` for your `venv` and it could be in `venv/bin/pip` (or similar folder) and `activate` should active also `pip`. But you can also use `venv/bin//pip` to install new version and install module`. OR  use only `python -m pip` and forget `pip`.